# Possible to have row breaks in a table spanning several slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is Powerpoint (2010) able to create row breaks for a table spanning over several slides?
If yes, how can the row breaking be controlled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint won't break anything from slide to slide automatically.  If you're creating a table in code, you'd need to track the height of the table as you add each row.  When the table height exceeds the max value you have in mind, you'd add another slide, add a table to it and start adding data to it.

Comment: Thanks!  The answer was as gloomy as I "feared".  So, if I have a sorted table spanning several slides, and  I want insert a new row, I have to shift and break the succeeding rows manually!? No shortcut?

Comment: Afraid so.  No shortcut.  With a word processing document, there's a bunch of text, graphics, tables etc. and the word processing app makes on-the-fly decisions about where to break pages.  In PowerPoint, slides are more like a folder full of separate documents in a word processor.  Content doesn't flow from one to the other.